# Android set a limit of installations allowed per .apk

Tags: android, security, activation

Is there a standard way to limit the number of installations allowed by an .apk

If I understand correctly Timestamp limits the time an .apk is valid for installation, is there something similar to this that limits the installation count.

I'm planning on using DeviceID and UserID to populate a DB that checks logs for used User ID / Device ID combination to allow or not allow access, once the app is installed.

Thing is I'm trying to prevent the app from even being installed if its over x number of installations.

I was thinking about something like:

```
package com.tchip.kw;
public class mysoft {
static {
  try{
    System.loadLibrary("tchipmysoft");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {}
}
public native int getmachinestatus1();
public native int getmachinestatus2();
}
 
///this will read/call 2 solutions from mysoft when the end users try to run app. If the return value is 0, then it will say’ Quit’. For example:
 
mysoft kw = new mysoft();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //this.findViewById(id)
        if (kw.getmachinestatus1() && kw.getmachinestatus2() )
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
/////Star splash activity
else
{
You do not have proper license to use this software and it will quit
}
}
```

I've thought about writing an installation .APK for the for the app.apk that checks for a set of  Key's held remotely and then grants access.

If there is a standardized method or am I missing something really simple, I'm all ears.